# Getting the active application on OS X 10.7 using a python daemon

Tags: python, objective-c, osx-lion, daemon, pyobjc

I'm trying to build a daemon in python and I want to get the name of the current active application.

For the daemon I'm using this nice [code snipped](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/) from Sander Marechal

The following line works perfectly on OS X 10.7 when I DON'T run the application as a daemon, although the documentation says "activeApplication()" was deprecated on 10.6+

```
activeAppName = str(NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().activeApplication()['NSApplicationName'])
```

But as soon as I run the application as a daemon, the application crashes.

However, the daemon doesn't crash when I only do

```
workspace = str(NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace())
```

which returns:

```
<NSWorkspace: 0x7ffe7cc013c0>
```

So my questions are:

1. Why does it crash only as a daemon?
2. How to get the active application via python on
   OS X 10.7 (which also works with a daemon ;-)) ?

I don't understand the error message, but maybe one of you does:

```
Process:         Python [7920]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  ??? [1]

Date/Time:       2012-02-29 23:35:25.202 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.3 (11D50b)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          818421 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           21
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   15
Anonymous UUID:                      05B412BD-4629-472B-964D-BE4A88B06DD1

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000108

VM Regions Near 0x108:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000102e90000-0000000102e91000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Application Specific Information:
*** single-threaded process forked ***
objc[7918]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ceb7ce9 _dispatch_wakeup + 108
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ceba876 _dispatch_resume_slow + 20
2   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x00007fff8d34f919 _ZL22connectToCoreServicesDv + 269
3   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x00007fff8d34f7d5 _ZL9getStatusv + 24
4   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x00007fff8d34f74f scCreateSystemServiceVersion + 50
5   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff90b5ace1 _ZL45SetupCoreApplicationServicesCommunicationPortv + 147
6   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff90b5b37a getProcessDispatchTable() + 19
7   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff90b56de0 LSClientSideSharedMemory::GetClientSideSharedMemory(LSSessionID, bool) + 158
8   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff90b6b152 _LSCopyFrontApplication + 42
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff899adc5d -[NSWorkspace activeApplication] + 26
10  libffi.dylib                    0x00007fff91df2e7c ffi_call_unix64 + 76
11  libffi.dylib                    0x00007fff91df3ae9 ffi_call + 728
12  _objc.so                        0x00000001031c7d60 PyObjCFFI_Caller + 2272
13  _objc.so                        0x00000001031dd169 0x1031ae000 + 192873
14  org.python.python               0x0000000102ea0d32 PyObject_Call + 97
15  org.python.python               0x0000000102f20f63 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 14353
16  org.python.python               0x0000000102f23df7 0x102e99000 + 568823
17  org.python.python               0x0000000102f20e0a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 14008
18  org.python.python               0x0000000102f23df7 0x102e99000 + 568823
19  org.python.python               0x0000000102f20e0a PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 14008
20  org.python.python               0x0000000102f23cd8 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1996
21  org.python.python               0x0000000102f23d4d PyEval_EvalCode + 54
22  org.python.python               0x0000000102f3b08f 0x102e99000 + 663695
23  org.python.python               0x0000000102f3b14f PyRun_FileExFlags + 157
24  org.python.python               0x0000000102f3c2a2 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 392
25  org.python.python               0x0000000102f4c2af Py_Main + 2715
26  org.python.python               0x0000000102e90e88 0x102e90000 + 3720
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some tests with this, and I think your issue might be the way you are daemonizing this tool and then trying to make a call that requires windows services that may not be available. This link here hints at such a situation: http://grokbase.com/t/python/pythonmac-sig/08axst378p/appscript-and-launching-apps-from-background-only-python-processes

I had first tested this theory using your daemon script and making an `osascript` call to find the active application via AppleScript:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = """osascript \
    -e 'tell application "System Events"' \
    -e 'set app_name to name of the first process whose frontmost is true' \
    -e 'end tell' """
v = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
```

Popen is a way to launch a system command in a subprocess and be able to check its return code or read its output (or send input) http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html. . Osascript is a command line tool for calling apple scripts.

For me, this works because its starting a new subprocess that I think **does** have access to the window server?

I then created a launchd plist instead of using your daemon script. This works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.company.test</string>
    <key>Nice</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/path/to/script.py</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Launchd is the OSX daemon process manager which does seem to launch programs in a way that they have complete access to the windowserver.

For `script.py`, I simply had it loop, writing the frontmost application name to a file and sleeping.

**Update**

Since you had mentioned that your pyobjc approach was deprecated, and you seemed to like the applescript approach, I thought I would tack on a pythonic way of doing that using [appscript - the python bindings to apple script](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/)

```
from appscript import app, its
activeApp = app('System Events').processes[its.frontmost == True].first()
print activeApp

#result
app(u'/System/Library/CoreServices/System Events.app').application_processes[u'Terminal']
```

`activeApp` is an object representing the frontmost application, reported by the System Events app.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but as I never worked with Applescript and Popen, can you explain shortly how the line with Popen works?

Comment: Updated.  Sorry, I made that assumption that you would already know popen. You are already into doing daemon scripts and using pyobjc, so I figured you would already know about popen. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I think launchd / launchctl is exactly what I need. Since you know how to write those files, can you recommend any good launchd tutorials?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not super experienced with writing launchd plist files or anything. I just grabbed one from the LaunchAgents directory and edited it. But there is apparently a really cheap app that generates them for you: http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/

Comment: @ka2011r: Check out my update for a pretty cool example of using the `appscript` apple script python bindings.

Answer (score 1):

The crash eventually happens in libdispatch, and it looks like it has something to do with shared memory; see the GetClientSideSharedMemory call in the call stack. So it looks like your daemonize code runs afoul of the [grand central dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch) technology built into OS X.

Have a look at the [python daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) module. It does things (conform [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/)) that the code snippet you are using overlooks.

Since OS X is basically a UNIX with extra bells and whistles, it is possible that you need to add some OS X specific steps when trying to run a program as a daemon.

You could study the source code of other daemons that work under OS X, like e.g. Postfix.